# removing element from ndarray of ndarrys

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 466 x 700 `numpy.ndarry`. For each `ndarray` within the 466 x 700 `ndarray`, I want to delete an element by index. This is what so far:

```
normalized_img = numpy.atleast_3d(img).astype(numpy.float) / 255.
for x, y in seam:
  numpy.delete(normalized_img[y], x)
```

`seam` consists of a coordinate tuple `(x, y)` and 
`img` is a 466 x 700 ndarray with `dtype=uint8`

I want to delete `(x, y)` from `normalized_img`. How do I do so? With `pdb.set_trace()`, I can see that it is still 466 x 700 even after I've gone iterated through all of `seam`. `seam` has a length of 466. I am expecting 466 x 699 after iterating through all of `seam`.

Example of `seam`: `(13,0), (12,1), (11,2), (10,3), ...` etc

I also tried:

```
normalized_img = numpy.atleast_3d(img).astype(numpy.float) / 255.
for x, y in seam:
  normalized_img[y] = numpy.delete(normalized_img[y], x)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seam_carver.py", line 118, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "seam_carver.py", line 114, in main
    sc = SeamCarver(image, int(width), int(height))
  File "seam_carver.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.seam_carve()
  File "seam_carver.py", line 79, in seam_carve
    normalized_img[y] = numpy.delete(normalized_img[y], x)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2099) into shape (700,3)
```

I believe this is due to mismatch of shapes but I am unsure of how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem readily but the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) states that numpy.delete returns:

> A copy of arr with the elements specified by obj removed. Note that
>   delete does not occur in-place. If axis is None, out is a flattened
>   array.

Meaning your changes do not apply to the array itself but to its copy, and additional steps are needed to have `normalized_img` modified.

This assumes that you're going to trim every row by one column (which is what you expect if the final array size is supposed to have one column less?)

```
tr_sz =(normalized_img.shape[0],normalized_img.shape[1]-1) 
temp = np.zeros(tr_sz)
for x, y in seam:
    temp[y] = np.delete(normalized_img[y], x)

normalized_img = temp
```